# Firebase Cloud Messaging : push notification, firefox app in foreground

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing FCM, and I'm struggling with receiving Firefox notification when app is in foreground : when the website tab where's the user has subscribed has been closed.
It's OK when website is focused or when it's in background.
It's also OK on Google Chrome with the 3 states : focus, background and foreground.
Push event is triggered, I can see it with this code in my service worker :

```js
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
  console.log('Push message received', event);
  self.console.log('self Push message received', event);
});
```

Here is my code to handle background (and foreground I hope) messages :

```js
messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function(payload) {
    const notificationOptions = {
        body: payload.data.body,
        icon: '[icon url]',
    };
    return self.registration.showNotification(payload.data.title, notificationOptions);
});
```

I've tried to add specific webpushconfig in the payload but nothing changes. I've also tried data type message and notification type message ( seen somewhere that data type message is better to receive background data ).

I'm not sure if it's the reason, but just noticed that I'm using "compat" scripts.

```js
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-app-compat.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.8.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js');
```

If it's the reason, I should  use the modular way to import scripts, If i'm correct.

Can someone helps me ? Perhaps it's not 100% available on Firefox ?

Thanks